# Can you count elements by image name using length() in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to put together a review "summary" section that totals the number of 5 star, 4 star, 3 star reviews etc.. What I need to do is count the instances of each "review level" on a product page and output the number. e.g. If a product has 50 reviews and 14 of them were 5 stars, I need to output that figure to the page as "14".

The only differentiator across reviews is not by an id or class, but the image name it outputs (which is the number of stars). See the image file names below for what I mean:

```
<ol class="ProductReviewList">
                <li class="">
        <h4 class="ReviewTitle">
            Cool hammock!
            <img src="http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/rc71b9995f4a706510d16ad47d2472c26eb88e9bf/themes/HealthBeauty/images/IcoRating4.png" alt="">
        </h4>
        <p class="Meta">
            Posted by Matina Keller on 6th Jan 2014
        </p>
        <p>I love this hammock! I got the single brazilian for my courtyard out the side and it fits snug between two patio posts. I can easily put it up and take it down whenever i want. It's really comfortable and easy to fall asleep in. The material is of very high quality and far better than my old hammock. Delivery was about 4 days to adelaide FYI.</p>
        <hr>
    </li>   <li class="Alt">
        <h4 class="ReviewTitle">
            So comfortable!
            <img src="http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/rc71b9995f4a706510d16ad47d2472c26eb88e9bf/themes/HealthBeauty/images/IcoRating5.png" alt="">
        </h4>
        <p class="Meta">
            Posted by Kendra Lovell on 17th Dec 2013
        </p>
        <p>I bought one of these for my daughter and she loves it. It's really comfortable and the colours are so pretty. Thanks siesta hammocks.</p>
        <hr>
    </li>   <li class="">
        <h4 class="ReviewTitle">
            Great customer service and product!
            <img src="http://cdn2.bigcommerce.com/rc71b9995f4a706510d16ad47d2472c26eb88e9bf/themes/HealthBeauty/images/IcoRating5.png" alt="">
        </h4>
        <p class="Meta">
            Posted by Susan Knight on 20th Nov 2013
        </p>
        <p>I must have had a million questions about this but the staff on the online chat answered all of them! Really good customer service and ordering system. The hammock itself is really good quality. So relaxing in the afternoon sun. Got the double hook kits and put it up between some wooden posts we already had under our pergola. Got the frame too in case we want to put it somewhere else. Really easy to assemble and is very sturdy. All up it's been a great experience shopping with siesta so thanks.</p>
        <hr>
    </li>
        </ol>
```

See at the very end how images are either IcoRating4.png or IcoRating5.png

I want to know if I can use .length() to count elements in the document not by id or class but by a string in their filename, or by image name or some variant like that. Is this possible?

[I've put together a fiddle here if that helps](http://jsfiddle.net/hLkhg/)

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like something that should be done in your backend prior to being fed into the front end, what if you were to start to paginate your reviews across multiple pages?

Comment: That was my next question. It's a bit tricky from the backend as it's a hosted solution ecommerce platform that is limited in what we can touch. Is it possible to then count elements on another URL apart from the page it is on? As when pagination kicks in, it basically creates a new URL with /reviews/pg2 appended on the end of the URL or something. Or can we only count elements on the current document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure can:

```
var count = $('img[src$="IcoRating4.png"]').length;
```

ref: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: Thanks mate will give this one a try now.

Comment: Just tried it and no output? Am I doing something wrong on the append side of things? - http://jsfiddle.net/hLkhg/1/

Comment: You needed to include the jQuery library and your concatenation for the output was wrong: http://jsfiddle.net/hLkhg/6/

Comment: Mate you're a legend. Thanks so much for your help!